# Could we remove the fade-in effect when opening a link to an answer or comment?

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, dark-mode

It looks especially ugly when dark mode is on (I tried on both Chrome and Firefox on Microsoft Windows), the bright flash hurts the eyes, and the length of the fade-in effect prevents me from reading the content for the first three seconds.

Demo using this [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/172051/1810):

[image]

Comment: I've always hated this effect for as long as it's existed. It's already completely useless on some pages where my screen jumps around (e.g. due to images loading because they don't have defined width and height attributes) and I don't even get to see which answer was highlighted in those few seconds. I'd rather it put a simple border around it permanently or something to emphasize where I was supposed to jump to, making it easy to locate the linked element on the page at any time.

Comment: @animuson yes, e.g. as YouTube does for comment links.

Comment: This has already been reported long ago: [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395983/4642212). This has actually been fixed for official dark mode. You’re using an extension for dark mode, which isn’t Stack Exchange’s job to fix. The `:target` highlight effect is very useful to determine what a link is actually pointing to, although maybe it’s time to drop the _animation_ part of this highlighting.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I use the official Chrome dark mode. Yes the request is about removing the fade-in effect, i.e. the animation part.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt … which isn’t the official Stack Overflow dark theme.

Comment: @SebastianSimon But Stack Exchange is supposed to work on Chrome.

Comment: One thing that happens with me is that when I go back to an answer link, the answers are arranged in a different random order, and so a different answer is scrolled to since the linked answer is in a different spot. I find the fade-in handy for that reason.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog "a different answer is scrolled to since the linked answer is in a different spot": do you have a link to show this behavior?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Load up any question that has two answers with the same score, and make sure you've sorted the answers by score. Follow a share link to one of the two same-scored answers. Refresh the page. There's a 50% chance that the two equivalently-scored answers will sort themselves in the opposite order and you'll be scrolled to the other answer, not the one you originally went to.